# sys.excepthook = handle_exception not invoket or trigeret

Tags: python, flask, exception

i have this simple flask app :

```
def handle_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    print("Hello")

dd = "test"
sys.excepthook = handle_exception
logger.info("a %s- b: %s" % dd)
# the logger above will raise exception 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start the app
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True)
```

the handle_exception never called 
but in the stdout/err Im getting :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1434, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/git/app/app.py", line 132, in <module>
    logger.info("a %s- b: %s" % dd)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

how to make it call the handle_exception? there i like to handle all exception that are not Were caughtאם

Comment: The exception you provided simply says that there are 2 `%s` in the format string while you have provided only one argument to it.

Comment: I know this , this is just example, the problem is that the sys.excepthook not invoke the function

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue without flask. Maybe something in the internals of flask is overriding excepthook

Comment: yeah flask have other error handling